# why SIGPIPE behaves different in different kernels?

Tags: signals, tail, sleep

I have two different systems running with linux and I'm getting some logs with

```
tail -f logfile
```

While `tail` was running, I sent `SIGPIPE` to `tail`'s process. `tail` continued to run on system 1 but died because of `SIGPIPE` at system 2. It's an example of `SIGPIPE` behaivors but it's a general question. Because I saw similiar behaviors for `sleep`, `script` etc.

Comment: Hard to say anything without knowing the kernels, distros and shells you used for these tests. According to the signal(7) man page, SIGPIPE's action is termination, but the signal can be ignored or handled.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04 on an ARM CPU, kernel 3.10.107-190, bash. SIGPIPE terminates the receiving process.

Comment: even the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/signal.h.html) seems to say SIGPIPE terminates the receiving process by default. It's up to the `tail` implementation to decide if to catch it and do something else. Not sure if there's any reason to do that in case of `tail`, but e.g. `tee` probably would want to catch it to be able to continue writing to the other destinations.